# Why is my Objective-C block not showing up when passed to Swift function?

Tags: swift, macos, objective-c-blocks, core-audio, audiounit

---

I'm failing to pass an objective-c block to a swift function.

---

I copied files from Apple example code for Audio Unit V3 to a fresh project, and something broke.

There is an Objective-C function that passes an anonymous block to a Swift file/function -- the Swift func is no longer working because it's not receiving the block properly.

When I put a breakpoint inside the Swift function, the variable for the passed-in block shows as `completionHandler (() -> ())` but with no address.

It should show `completionHandler (()->()) 0xd8d87999` or whatever.  (And it should pass this to another Swift function, which it is no longer able to call.)

The rest of the Swift code is working AFAIK.

Any ideas much appreciated.

---

The Objective-C function:
 
(trying to pass `^{[self connectParametersToControls];}` to Swift object, "playEngine")

```
playEngine = [[SimplePlayEngine alloc] initWithComponentType: desc.componentType componentsFoundCallback: nil];
[playEngine selectAudioUnitWithComponentDescription_objc:desc
                                          completionHandler:^{
                                             [self connectParametersToControls];
                                          }];
```

The Swift function:

```swift
@objc public func selectAudioUnitWithComponentDescription_objc(_ componentDescription: AudioComponentDescription, completionHandler: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
      self.selectAudioUnitWithComponentDescription(componentDescription, completionHandler:completionHandler)
}
```

The relevant line in the Swift header:

```c
- (void)selectAudioUnitWithComponentDescription_objc:(AudioComponentDescription)componentDescription completionHandler:(void (^ _Nonnull)(void))completionHandler;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out although Obj-c optimization was off, the Swift optimization was on, and this was causing the problem.  I don't suppose it should, but this seems to be the case.